# Ubuntu 16 RAID5 running but primary GPT table is corrupt on 3 of 4 drives

Tags: gpt, gdisk

RAID5 is operating but GPT has CRC error and/or is corrupt (depending on who give the error message).

I have read all of the helps I can find on this and I did what they said and it worked... once only.  But for the other 3 disks in the RAID, I also get the same message and gdisk won't fix the other 3.  It seems to but there is no change.  Even rebooted.  Still no change.  I get the error from fdisk and gparted.

```
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 732EB483-B100-11E6-93EA-1CC1DE626522
```

It used to see it for sda, b, c and d. I did the steps with gdisk on sda.  No more message.  I was happy.  Did the same steps on b, c and d and the error does not go away for these three drives.

I really would like to get rid of this and have a healthy and happy drives.

Thanks for any pointers on this beyond the failing gdisk.

Mike

Comment: Overnight, I thought that I should try to --stop the RAID array and then fix the other 3 disks then --assemble --scan if back to life.  After stopping Samba, I could stop the array and ran gpart on each of the 3 drives and they stopped complaining.  However, I could not reassemble the RAID from any command I could find.  It claimed that the superblocks were gone off the 3 drives I just fixed.  I did not check about the first one I fixed while the array was running yesterday.  So I restarted the 5 day build all over again.  Thank goodness I "only" had 1.5 TB loaded onto it so far.  5 more days.

Comment: What type of RAID are you using? There are three types: True hardware RAID (most common on servers), motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID," managed by the Linux `dmraid` tools), and Linux software RAID (managed by the Linux `mdadm` tools). Given your symptoms, I suspect you're using "fake RAID," but that the configuration is incomplete or you're accessing individual disks rather than the assembled RAID device. I suggest you read the [Fake RAID HOWTO,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) re-assess, and edit your question or post a new one.